# Eclipse Android config file always returns null

Tags: android, eclipse

Currently in the process of creating a testing framework for Android via Eclipse and JUnit. The last thing I'm implementing is a Configuration file and reader so that the config file can be used to change various properties when necessary. The structure of my framework is as follows:

```
MainFramework (project)
  Base package
  Utility package
    Config class

Testing (project)
  examples package
    Artist testing class
```

The Config class is as follows:

public class Config {

```
private static Config instance;
public Context context;
public static Properties prop;

public static StorefrontConfig getInstance(Context context) {

    if(instance == null)
        instance = new StorefrontConfig(context);
    return instance;
}

protected StorefrontConfig(Context cont) {
    context = cont;
    AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream instream = manager.open("config");
        readConfig(instream);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("cool", "Failed to create properly initialized config class");
    }
}

private static void readConfig(InputStream instream) {

    try {
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));

        while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split_line = line.split("=", 2);
            prop.setProperty(split_line[0], split_line[1]);
        }

        prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"), "Default and local config files");
        read.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("cool", "Failed to create properly initialized config class");
    }
}

public String getProperty (String propertyKey) {

    try {
        return prop.getProperty(propertyKey);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("cool", "Failed to access property");
        return null;
    }
}

public Context getContext () {
    return context;
}
```

When I call the getProperty() method in my code, it always returns null. However, I have no idea if it is failing to initially read and write the values or what is going on. All I know is that my program works with hard-coded values but not when using this class and referencing it via config.getProperty() in the code where needed (my main framework has a Config class that is inherited by all the tests).

Any help would be really appreciated. Only thing I can think of is that Java's Properties class cannot be used with Android?

Answer (score 0):

Java's Properties can be used with Android.

It looks like you aren't instantiating `prop`, which probably results in a `NullPointerException` when you call `prop.getProperty(propertyKey)`. At some point you need to instantiate `prop` with `prop = new Properties();`. Check out [these examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/). Number 2 will probably make your life easier, as you don't need to manually parse the properties file like you do in `readConfig()`.